# A catchy way to say that someone "backed off from a deal"

Tags: expressions, idioms, synonyms

I need to find an expression, idiom, or image to say: "They backed off from the deal before it even started."

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You mean besides something like "renege"?

Comment: The idea is to start a pleading with an catchy phrase that basically says:

" Mr. X back off the deal, before it even started" But in a more catchy way. Hope that clarifies it a little bit

Comment: You need to explain more carefully what you are trying to accomplish by the term you are seeking. Why is 'backed off from the deal before it even started' not catchy enough for that purpose? Asking for a catchy term, without further explanation, creates a risk that the question will be interpreted as opinion-based, which would put it outside the scope of this site.

Comment: Did they change their mind? Were they being deceitful and never intended to enter the deal? Were they cowardly? Did they realise the deal was immoral and listen to their conscience? Were they pressured to renege?

Comment: 'Back/ed out of' is the usual multi-word verb. 'Go back on' includes an element of betrayal.

Answer (score 1):

You don't specify the reason(s) that someone backs off from a deal before it is finalized, but one way of summing reasons up is to say that they **(get) cold feet.**

> **cold feet**
>
> Apprehension or doubt strong enough to prevent a planned course of
> action [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cold%20feet#:%7E:text=Definition%20of%20cold%20feet,a%20planned%20course%20of%20action)

> Loss of nerve or confidence.
>
> *Hels's flat sale has fallen through - the purchaser was intending to buy-to-let and has got cold feet over the interest rates.* [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/cold_feet)

---

> Or if you suspect someone could **get cold feet** at the last moment,
> you might pledge to discuss ways to save the deal before **walking away
> from the negotiating table**. [David Hames; *Closing Deals, Settling
> Disputes, and Making Team Decisions*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Negotiation_Closing_Deals_Settling_Dispu/5d_FudyDtxQC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22get%20cold%20feet%22%20back%20off%20a%20deal%20before%20it%20started&pg=PA401&printsec=frontcover) (2011)

> Beware of virgin angels. Experienced angels make funding decisions
> quicker and with fewer surprises. Virgin angels may **back out when they
> get cold feet**. [Stephen Harper; *Extraordinary Entrepreneurship*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Extraordinary_Entrepreneurship/9Kvv2Yv67jYC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=cold%20feet%20back%20off%20a%20deal%20before%20it%20started&pg=PA347&printsec=frontcover) (2006)

> So, the project went on as planned, and for a while Tina thought she
> was immune from deportation. As time when on, the other party became
> more and more worried about the ever-increasing and rigorous ID
> investigations that he **got cold fee and bailed out**. So, the deal
> was off. [Min-Hwa Kennard; *From Sea to Sea*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/From_Sea_to_Sea/5b1WEAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=cold%20feet%20back%20off%20a%20deal%20before%20it%20started&pg=PT108&printsec=frontcover) (2021)

> His dream popped quickly. The economy began to slow, and the investors
> he had been working with started to **get cold feet**. [Rick Newman;
> *Rebounders*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Rebounders/qhsVliVRZ50C?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=cold%20feet%20back%20off%20a%20deal%20before%20it%20started&pg=PA44&printsec=frontcover) (2012)